# Automation of Export logs from CloudWatch to S3 bucket in a time interval

Tags: python, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have some resources are running in AWS infrastructure and logs are being found in CloudWatch.

Is there anyway I can automate or write some script, which will automatically export my logs every week or month to S3 bucket?

Comment: This question is off topic - imho in multiple qay. It is too broad and seems to ask for tutorials / 3rd party ressources.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple ways to do this.

1. Stream logs directly to S3 [Using CloudWatch Logs Subscription Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html)
2. Use a CloudWatch Scheduled event to schedule a Lambda function to run a log export to S3. Here's a quick tutorial ([Export Log Data to Amazon S3 Using the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasks.html)) on how to do it using the CLI but the command should be similar for Boto3 within Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lambda function to automate this process.

Here is an article on how to do it:

https://aws.plainenglish.io/export-aws-cloudwatch-logs-to-s3-using-lambda-functions-in-node-js-b97e2afa0ac